# How do I link my products directly to external in Woocommerce shop page and conserve the shop page display?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to link products on my Woocommerce shop page directly to the external/affiliate site by clicking on the product's image.
In content-product.php file I changed

```
    <a href="<?php  the_permalink(); ?>">
```

by

```
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $product->get_product_url() ) ?>">
```

It works but changes the shop page display: only one of 7 product is displayed and it changed the photo size. https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RQ7x.jpg

Anyone has a trick please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see anything in their docs that mentions a get_product_url() method for the Product object. Are you using an extension to allow affiliate tracking? or did you add the custom field yourself to the product page?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it worked for me!!

```
add_action('plugins_loaded','your_function_name');
function your_function_name() {

   add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item','new_link_opening',10);

}
function new_link_opening() {

    echo '<a href="http://www.google.com" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link">';

}
```